# sum specific columns among rows

Tags: r, sum

I need to sum every two columns
for example

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
12  2   3   7
1   4   6   5
```

I need

```
X1     X2
14     10
5      11
```

I tried apply function
and I tried this function 
mat is a matrix

```
mat1=matrix()

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
for(j in 1:ncol(mat)){
mat1[i,j]=mat[j,i]+mat[j,i+1]
}}
```

Comment: A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's answer uses `split.default`. Relevant: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
 mat[,c(TRUE,FALSE)]+mat[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]

  x1 x3
1 14 10
2  5 11
```

Answer (score 8):

A generalization of this problem (for a `data.frame`) might be something like:

```
sapply(split.default(mydf, 0:(length(mydf)-1) %/% 2), rowSums)
#       0  1
# [1,] 14 10
# [2,]  5 11
```

Replace the "2" in `%/% 2` with the number of sets of columns you would like to "aggregate".

Answer (score 1):

```
id <- 1:ncol(mat)
mat[ , id[id%%2!=0] ] + mat[ , id[id%%2==0] ]
     x1 x3
[1,] 14 10
[2,]  5 11
```